# getReadConnection() error

Tags: database, reports, resource-model

I am trying to follow

http://codemagento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/

the simple report example.

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object in /Volumes/Apache/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 134

I can pastebin any code you wanna see but does anyone have any idea why I'm seeing that?

Comment: Code from the model and resource model would be great.

Answer (score 7):

You have this? It looks like you have no resource model.

```
<models>
    <awesome>
        <class>Super_Awesome_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>awesome_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </awesome>
     <awesome_mysql4>
        <class>Super_Awesome_Model_Mysql4</class>
</models>
```

You have to define the class and the resource model.

```
class Super_Awesome_Model_Simple extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('awesome/simple');
    }
}
```

and the resource model:

```
class Super_Awesome_Model_Mysql4_Simple extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $mainTable = 'simple'; // check the node in the config.xml
        $idFieldName = 'simple_id'; // whatever the column is named.
        $this->_init($mainTable, $idFieldName)
    }
}
```

And to be up to date change now every Mysql4 to Resource. Mysql4 is outdated. Today the resource models are named `Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_MyModel`

Comment: the only code I was missing was that last block

Comment: when I added it, it gives me: "Fatal error: Class VMR_Rtest_Model_Mysql4_Simple contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_getReadAdapter, Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_getWriteAdapter) in /Volumes/Apache/mage/app/code/local/VMR/Rtest/Model/Mysql4/Simple.php on line 11"  (Bear in mind, I'm using VMR_Rtest instead of that super_awesome stuff)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, you have to extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`

Comment: It just flew through my twitter stream https://www.creare.co.uk/magento-model-basics-the-complete-series

Comment: where I can found these files?

Comment: Which files? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error. When i checked by `system.log` of Magento, i got message

> "2013-06-26T07:03:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(<Namespace>/<ModuleName>/Model/Mysql4/<FileName>.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/<site-name>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93"

Then i checked in my directory that this particular file was missing. After creating the file, the issue was gone.

Comment: This was the issue for me too. Thanks a lot!